# How to create AppArmor profiles for docker containers

Tags: docker, apparmor

I'm starting to dig into AppArmor and since nearly all my services run in a docker container I would like to create profiles for these containers, as mentioned in the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/).
Has anybody experience with this, so can I somehow use `aa-genprof` with a docker container, to semi-automate the process?

Greetings

mathas

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you're asking. I don't think it's as seamless as `aa-genprof` but hopefully will speed up the process of creating profiles.

https://github.com/genuinetools/bane